# Can't import orfeo-toolbox algorithms in QGIS Python scripts

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, orfeo-toolbox

So I installed Orfeo-Toolbox on my Windows machine and it's working fine within the QGIS GUI application. But I would like to use OTB algorithms in QGIS Python standalone scripts. So when I load the processing module and list the algorithms it shows all the algorithms (native, QGIS, SAGA etc). But I can't use otb algorithms for some reason. This is my code:

```
import sys
qgis_python_path = "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.20.0\\apps\\qgis\\python"
qgis_site_package_path = "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.20.0\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages"
qgis_plugin_path = "C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.20.0\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins"
sys.path.append(qgis_python_path)
print("ff")
sys.path.append(qgis_python_path)
sys.path.append(qgis_site_package_path)
sys.path.append(qgis_plugin_path)
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsRasterLayer
from qgis import processing
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 3.16\\apps\\qgis", True)
qgs.initQgis()
from plugins import processing as p
from plugins.processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
cluster_params = {}
processing.run("otb:KMeansClassification",cluster_params)
qgs.exitQgis()
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\qgistest.py", line 19, in <module>
    processing.run("otb:KMeansClassification",cluster_params)
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 156, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm otb:KMeansClassification not found
```

I know I haven't passed the parameters to the algorithm. But the problem is QGIS doesn't list OTB algorithms at all.